# file path as parameter from controller to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I have a problem, I need to pass a filepath from my controller to view from a grid. Normally this is no problem, I just do this:

```
new GridColumnSettings { Member = "Name", Width = "100px", Title = "Title",
  ClientTemplate = "<a onclick='Function(\"<#=Parameter#>\")'><#=Name#></a>" },
```

However now I need to pass a file path that I get from the database. The path of-course looks like this: `\\folder\file.txt`

The problem is that in Jquery/javascript a single backslash doesn't work. So when I check the value of my parameter now it'll say `\\folderfile.txt`

Anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: How are you currently passing the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slash by using `\\` instead of `\`

Look at right hand column on the [json spec](http://www.json.org/)

You might look at [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for all your serialization.